after upgrade from 24.04 to 24.10: issue of keeps logging out on i5, 8 GB RAM, NVIDIA GTZ 660 GPU, Nouveau driver
I have desktop with i5 CPU 760 @ 2.8 GHz, 8 GB RAM and NVIDIA GeForce GTZ 660 graphic card. This computer had ubuntu 24.04 running without any problems with NVIDIA 470 driver. Couple of weeks ago I upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10. Now I am using nouveau driver because NVIDIA can not be installed as it is not available in 24.10 repositories and other more recent drivers available that are available in repositories provide lowest display resolution and no options to select high resolutions. Now the issue is computer keeps loging me out too frequently and I have to login again every few minutes. Is there way to fix this issue or will I have to go back to 24.04. I do not have much technical knowledge of computers or ubuntu.
This is issue is specific to upgrade from ubuntu 24.04 to 24.10. Solutions that were applicable to previous versions of ubuntu do not work with 24.10 because Nvidia 470 driver is not available in ubuntu 24.10 ppa repositories

This question is similar to: How do I install the Nvidia drivers?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you read the question carefully you should easily realize it is not the same question.

The reason why I chose this question and not whatever is because you can't find a compatible Nvidia proprietary graphics driver in the default Ubuntu repositories, so you need to download it from the official Nvidia website. Why do you think that this doesn't answer your question?
